# How to make ScrollView width = to device screen width?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uiscrollview

I am making an app that has a (child) View inside a Scroll View. I understand I have to explicitly set the child View's width since the Scroll View won't provide that information to the child, but how can I make this child View's width auto-adjust based on the width of the device?

For example, in the below I've set the width to 380 which centers the "Quotes" in iPhone 6, but makes them slightly right of center in iPhone 5.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you need a screen width, look for it at `[UIScreen mainScreen]`. Keep in mind though that it is orientation-independent at iOs 8 as opposed to the earlier iOs versions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use auto layout to set the width of your subView equal to your main View by performing a control drag from your subView to your main View like this:

[image]

Then select "Equal Widths" from the popup

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select viewController

Stretch the view you want full screen size to the size of the screen

Click the central icon from the three choices along the bottom of the window

You will an icon pop up

The top 4 values will have a dotted red line joining them

click them all

at the bottom of the pop up you will see 'add 4 constraints'

click this

Done!

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the constraint for width. The view will place it self horizontally becuase of the leading and trailing space to superview. No need for a specific width.

I think your scrollview will be scrolling vertically so in that case you probably need to provide a constraint for the height or your view, and update scrollview contentsize accordingly to this.

Answer (score 0):

Since your child view is located in the view hierarchy of your view controller's view you can assign constraints between your child view and your view controller's view.

Ctrl drag from your child view to your view controller's view. You will see option to set them to have equal widths. Select it. Then adjust the constant if you want the width of your child view to be lower.

You can then add leading and trailing constraints between your child view and your scroll view.

Doing it in this way will also ensure that you set the content width of you scroll view dynamically and correctly.

Let me know if it works for you